# Local By Flywheel - Error establishing a database connection

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I was working on a website for a client a week ago and I came back to make further edits, but whenever I want to access the website, it reads:

> Error establishing a database connection

I checked my `wp-config` file and everything is untouched; I did not touch one single line of code here when setting up my new Wordpress project in Local by Flywheel.

All my other local websites work except for this one. I've provided an image of my workspace just to make it more clear.

[image]

Looking at this image, the *MySQL Version* is a little bit off. The version should in fact be `5.6.37`, but instead it's reading an older version of MySQL.

I did try closing and reopening Local by Flywheel, but it had no effect.

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the site name and click on “Reveal in Finder” in Local by      Flywheel.

Compress the folder containing all your site in a *.ZIP file (normally there must be at least the “app” and “logs” folder, sometimes “conf”).

In Local by Flywheel, import the site manually in FILE / IMPORT SITE, choose the Zip of your site

Normally, it reinstalls the site and recreates the Database … for me it’s work (on Windows and on Mac)

Comment: I just tried it on Windows 10 and it did work, thank you very much! Just as a heads up for anyone coming across this issue, make sure you restart your computer before trying any fixes. This fix was not working until I restarted my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to compare your wp-config.php file in the broken site to a site that is using the same MySQL server?

I know you said that the file is untouched, but check again that all of the define parameters are correct.

Next I would suggest logging into your MySQL server using the credentials you have listed in the wp-config.php file and ensure you are able to access your database.